# Is there a way we can update the url that starts with '/' using Python and Beautiful soup

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Here is what i am facing problem the anchor tag **href** starts with **/abcd.html**
I want to update it to **href="https://www.example.com/abcd.html"** in the **BeautifulSoup** instance itself

is this possible ?

Answer (score 1):

To change the `href` parameter of `<a>` tag, just assign to `'href'` key of selected link.

For example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

txt = '''
<html>
<a href="/abcd.html" title="link">Some link</a>
</html>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

# find link, <a> tag
link = soup.find('a')

# change href attribute in <a>
link['href'] = 'https://www.example.com' + link['href']

# print soup
print(soup.prettify())
```

Prints:

```
<html>
 <a href="https://www.example.com/abcd.html" title="link">
  Some link
 </a>
</html>
```